# Reference Complex type from union in Typescript

Tags: typescript, graphql-codegen

I'm using `graphql-codegen` to generate types from my graphQL queries.

The result is sometimes pretty complex specifically when `unions` are involved.

Here is a concrete example

```js
export type GroupQuery = { __typename?: 'Query' } & {
  group?: Maybe<
    { __typename?: 'Group' } & Pick<
      Group,
      'id' | 'name' 
    > & {
        criterions: Array<
          { __typename?: 'kindA' } & Pick<SomeModel, 'id' | 'type'> | 
          { __typename?: 'kindB' } & Pick<SomeOtherModel, 'id' | 'type' | 'count'>
        >
    }
  }
```

So I'm trying to do is be able to refer to a specific case of the union based on the `__typename`

```
let kindB: NonNullable<GroupQuery['group']>['criterions'][0]// not sure where to go from here.
```

Maybe a utility type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type:

```
type T = NonNullable<GroupQuery['group']>['criterions'][0]`
```

Would be resolved to this type:

```
type T = {
    __typename?: "kindA" | undefined;
    id: number;
    name: string;
} | {
    __typename?: "kindB" | undefined;
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

So what you are really asking how to get the branch of the union where:

```
__typename === 'kindB'
```

In that case you can use an intersection `&` to filter a union type. In general that works like this:

```
type T = ("A" | "B" | "C") & "A" // "A"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=8&ssc=9&pln=8&pc=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQgYSgXigIhmqAfdcu5oJoBQokUA8gHYA2IMKsiUAZOplAPRcekk8oAdQD2AJwDWAZxIBjEdSnAoAQwBcVOgyYZ+ggGIqAlrRnzFygEYaa9RqjT4gA)

So you can use an intersection to make the union resolve to only the type that could match the intersected type.

```
type KindB =
    NonNullable<GroupQuery['group']>['criterions'][0] & { __typename: 'kindB' }
```

Now `KindB` resolves to this type:

```
type KindB = {
    __typename?: "kindB" | undefined;
    id: number;
    name: string;
} & {
    __typename: 'kindB';
}
```

As you can see, the `kindA` member of the union is no longer present, and the remaining member of the union is being intersected with `{ __typename: 'kindB' }`.  If you apply that intersection, it reduces to:

```
type KindB = {
    __typename: "kindB";
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

[Playground with working code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDiUIFcwEUvBSJwC8cA3gFBw1wDmmOA-AFwXW2cCWAJmwHZYAtgCNCAGg6ca-AIZDgbAM4woXfnUnTaAYzUxCXCPyVsAglCizEAHinba5OAH1nSFHIWs4AcgDW6jxmPuJwvALCYlChnopwKmoaoQC+cAA+cPYOFC5uyMCx3v6BAEIhYXxwgqISVfJxCeqacMlZtAB89q2tlO6oANKlpHAAcsYjWAA2k7Iik8A2GNh4BEQA2j4Myz4Auu0belwGasZKu2sADDtwAGQ5rn2xbMX8PGUtlJQA9F9wAOrQPxKSjzeABV4lNiDCHDKicB75J6+cFvEL2cJwACMACYAMxaWhInxCYixNE9H5wABisi4k2BoLgKJKNLpmKhQzIcNoCI89WezPJn0prPpIOAYNKouxHJhXPsvIK-ORgWCBJoGJx+PsRJJdQUQsoQA)

---

With some refactoring, you could even make this quite nice with a nice generic type alias:

```
// Union of all criterion types
type GroupQueryCriterions =
    NonNullable<GroupQuery['group']>['criterions'][number]

// Get the branch of the criterions union that has a specific typename.
type GroupQueryCriterionType<T extends GroupQueryCriterions['__typename']> =
    GroupQueryCriterions & { __typename: T }

// Get a specific criterion type.
type KindB = GroupQueryCriterionType<'kindB'>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=21&ssc=46&pln=12&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDiUIFcwEUvBSJwC8cA3gFBw1wDmmOA-AFwXW2cCWAJmwHZYAtgCNCAGg6ca-AIZDgbAM4woXfnUnTaAYzUxCXCPyVsAglCizEAHinba5OAH1nSFHIWs4AcgDW6jxmPuJwvALCYlChnopwKmoaoQC+cAA+cPYOFC5uyMCx3v6BAEIhYXxwgqISVfJxCeqacMlZtAB89q2tlAD0vXAAqvxG-HAQAGZwsgA2M3B6XAZqxgj5SpTuqBjYeAREAML6hsZKpPYAcsYXWHOyIjPANjs4+ISIANo+DLs+ALrtL6LZajJT-D7VKJ-Sh9AZoYDwGAAC1QIis-B0SPGU2RqGBJxMcCwI1WyNk8CRsjOsniKB0XAmXB0aw89QAdJt8uhGHt3kclgSACr5GyCuCgAz8HhnF68w7HFYmL6uLaxf7tc6cWVveUCxVnABkORV+VibDFPX66AR01pwHpjOZ+MVLOAHK2cAA0qVSNzdjrEPyQcZhSgbMUpWVOrC4AAxWRcGZKNlwABEASlsdTYTO-Ag8BpADdZrxcqr6pyUF7ArHfdr9oGFaNQ08IzxYz5o1aAOrQPwbR7wDM8Epsb2R31UTgm1kKNhtspaWjhOAARgATABmJcyerzoTENWSS0DeOJgc24clM8zVdjn1kKe0GcFPe+K8hSgnuMJpOUQdwFeN7rveE6PvYL5mu+gTBDuFRsBu272FBPgHnUCifj0QA)